# Certificates, and multiple CNAME records

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate

If I host a service that has `endsystem.example.org` as it's URL, and it is hosting a certificate for `www.example.org`, and I have a CNAME `intermediate.example.org` that points to `endsystem.example.org`, and a CNAME `www.example.org` that points to `intermediate.example.org`, will the certificate work for a user in the browser, or will it be considered a man-in-the-middle attack ? Or perhaps fail because `intermediate.example.org` is not part of the certificate ?

So the scenario is: `www.example.org` -> `intermediate.example.org` -> `endsystem.example.org`, and endsystem.example.org is hosting a certificate for www.example.org, will a browser accept it ?

**Why do this ?**

The URL of `endsystem.example.org` changes from time to time, and I control both `endsystem.example.org` and `intermediate.example.org`, so I have no problem updating `intermediate.example.org` when `endsystem.example.org` changes.

I don't control the CNAME for `www.example.org`, so I need to add this "middle-man", to adjust for the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what the browser cares about is that the hostname portion of the URL matches the subject name (one of the SANs) in the certificate presented by the server it connected to.

The CNAMEs are not really a factor in this, these affect how the IP address that the browser connects to was resolved on the DNS level, but the browser location URL is not affected in any way by these CNAMEs.

Comment: Thanks alot for a really quick response. I'll update the question explaining why this is even relevant.

Comment: I have the same setup but I need to invoke an API over HTTPS on `intermediate.example.org` and I can't use `www.example.org` to call the API. When I try this, I get a certificate error because the hostname doesn't match what's in the certificate. I can't disable HTTPS or certificate validation and I can't change the subject name in the cert. Is there a way for the server to serve multiple certificates? One for `www.example.org` and the other `intermediate.example.org`?

Comment: @Vinayak In theory that is possible based on SNI. In practice it depends on the web server software that terminates TLS in your case, another option would be a single certificate with both names (SAN). Consider posting your own question with all the details.

Comment: I'll do that if we decide to go this route. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit to follow up to change in question:

From the user's perspective it only matters what the final URL is and whether the certificate matches that URL.  If you have control over intermediate.example.org but the user is going to endsystem.example.org the certificate needs to be valid for endsystem.example.org.  You can accomplish that with the methods I listed below.  If the URL for endsystem.example.org is changing but you have control to put the certificate in place for that site then you would be best suited to have a wildcard certificate in place instead of having to purchase a new certificate each time the URL changes.

The browser will only accept the certificate as valid for the site if the subject of the certificate has a CN entry matching your FQDN or if there is a Subject Alternative Name entry for the FQDN of the site the user is visiting.

As an example look at the certificate for this site and you'll see a whole list of Subject Alternative Names which allow that single certificate to work across all of their sites.

```
DNS Name=*.stackexchange.com
DNS Name=stackoverflow.com
DNS Name=*.stackoverflow.com
DNS Name=stackauth.com
DNS Name=sstatic.net
DNS Name=*.sstatic.net
DNS Name=serverfault.com
DNS Name=*.serverfault.com
DNS Name=superuser.com
...
```

Another option is to do a wildcard certificate which would cover all of your example.org sites.

Comment: I've added an explanation of why I want to do this, perhaps this helps you understand my challenge.

Comment: Updated answer based on your update to the question @CodeMonkey

Comment: "the certificate needs to be valid for endsystem.example.org" - I wonder if that is correct (do you mean it has to be part of the certificate?). This is actually a Cloudfront (CDN) issue, and when you create a CloudFront distribution you can give it a Certificate to use. And currently I have several sites running where xyz.cloudfront.com is not part of the certificate, but the certificate is valid in the browser none-the-less, since the CNAME www.example.org -> xyz.cloudfront.com is ok.

Comment: But to clarify, the user will visit "www.example.org" in the browser, and the purpose is for the CNAME records to end up at endsystem.example.org, while ensuring the certificate is valid in the browser.

Comment: A CNAME record doesn't actually redirect the browser to endsystem.example.org so the URL should still be www.example.org.  The client does the DNS lookup for www.example.org and gets a CNAME record sending the user to endsystem.example.org.  That IP/server in the background doesn't matter the user as long as the site URL is www.example.org and the certificate matches www.example.org.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully these comments can help others :-)